# update array calling different methods in class

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, the_name, the_method):
        self.the_name = the_name
        self.the_method = the_method

    def evaluation(self, the_name):
        the_name = self.the_name
        the_method = self.the_method

        if the_method == 'A':
            the_name = np.where(
                    np.logical_or(
                        the_name < themin,
                        the_name > themax),
                    the_name, self.replace(the_name)
                )
        return the_name

    def replace(self, the_name):
        the_name = self.the_name
        the_method = self.the_method

        the_name[:] = 3333
        return the_name


the_method = 'A'
themin = 30
themax = 100
the_name = np.array([1, 22, 36, 34, 49, 60, 79, 101, 124, 147])
theobj = MyClass(the_name, the_method).evaluation(the_name)

print(the_name)
```

Result: `[3333 3333 3333 3333 3333 3333 3333 3333 3333 3333]`

I am first checking in the evaluation method, if the method I want is the one (in this example the `A` method).

Then, I want to apply some criteria. If the value of `the_name is < themin or > themax`, then leave the specific elements of the `the_name` as they are.

If they are not, call the `replace` method.

But, I want the replace method to act on the updated `the_name`.

Right now, the result is wrong.

I want `[1 22 3333 3333 3333 3333 3333 101 124 147]` as result.

---- Another senario -----------

If I have something like this:

```
def evaluation(self, array):

        if self.the_method == 'A':

            if np.any(array < themin):

                self.replace(array)

        return array

def replace(self, array):
        return np.average(array)
```

So, I want to compute the average of the whole array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use `np.where`? You can simply replace all elements of an array that obey a certain condition using [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
mask = np.logical_and(the_name >= themin, the_name <= themax)
the_name[mask] = the_name.mean() # or 3333
```

Should do the trick. So the full code would look like this:

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, the_name, the_method):
        self.the_name = the_name
        self.the_method = the_method

    def evaluation(self, the_name):
        the_name = self.the_name
        the_method = self.the_method

        if the_method == 'A':
            mask = np.logical_and(the_name >= themin, the_name <= themax)
            the_name[mask] = self.replace(the_name)
            return the_name

    def replace(self, the_name):
        return the_name.mean() # or 3333?


the_method = 'A'
themin = 30
themax = 100
the_name = np.array([1, 22, 36, 34, 49, 60, 79, 101, 124, 147])
theobj = MyClass(the_name, the_method).evaluation(the_name)

print(the_name)
```

Results:

For the `mean` version: `[  1  22  65  65  65  65  65 101 124 147]`

For the `3333` version: `[   1   22 3333 3333 3333 3333 3333  101  124  147]`

I'm not sure whether `the_name = self.the_name` at the beginning of `evaluation` is actually doing what you think it does btw.

Comment: If I want the mean of the whole array?So, the_name will contain the mean value

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want. I thought you wanted to replace specific values of the array (between `themin` and `themax`) with either 3333 or the arrays mean which is `65.3` rounding down to `65` because you have an integer array.

Comment: In the second senario in my post , I just have a condition.If any  value in the array  < min for example, then calculate the mean for the whole array

Comment: And do what with the mean? In your example you return it to the evaluate function which actually does nothing with the return value. Can you specify  more clearly (preferably in your question) what you want your program to do? Namely, what output you expect for what input and maybe even some reasoning as to why you are doing what you are doing as there may be even easier solutions to you original problem...

Comment: I just want the evaluate function , in the end (after calling the replace) to return the mean value.Do nothing else.Just check if condition is met and then call replace.I hope it is clear.thanks!

Comment: So to combine your two scenarios, you want to check whether there is any value smaller than `themin`. If so, you want to return the mean of the array, else you want to replace all values between `themin` and `themax` with 3333? Did I get that correct now? Also, do you want to change the global array `the_name` or do you want to return a changed array. Your mixing of names is really confusing.

Comment: The solution you gave in the above post is ok, so please don't edit anything.If you want to combine them , be my guest :).The second senario is a different thing from the original post.It is just about checking if any value < min then compute the mean and return the `the_name` array, not a changed one.Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I rolled back to the original solution. I hope this answers the question for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134568/discussion-between-george-and-jotasi).

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, the_name, the_method):
        self.the_name = the_name
        self.the_method = the_method

    def replace(self, item):

        item = 3333
        return item

    def evaluation(self, array):

        if self.the_method == 'A':

            array = [self.replace(x) if ((x>themin)&(x<themax)) else x for x in array]

        return array

the_method = 'A'
themin = 30
themax = 100
the_name = np.array([1, 22, 36, 34, 49, 60, 79, 101, 124, 147])
theobj = MyClass(the_name, the_method).evaluation(the_name)

print(theobj)
```

out:

```
[1, 22, 3333, 3333, 3333, 3333, 3333, 101, 124, 147]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But, the way `replace` method I want to work,is by acting upon `the_name`.(I want to update `the_name` in order to use it for other actions as well)

Comment: thats still doable with that base code. just got edit a few things. one of the issues as stuntman pointed was that you were replacing the full array with 3333's

Comment: And what if in the replace function, I want to compute the average of the whole array?So, replace the array with it's average (numpy.average)?Check [here](http://pastebin.com/k6kkmke5) for example

Comment: i can work out the code for you but you gotta explain explicity/properly what you need. you can edit your original post and i ll look into it when i have some spare time mate

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is within your replace method. The line `the_name[:] = 3333` was replacing `self.the_name` with an array of 3333's. If you change replace to return a **new** array of the same length, filled with 3333's, then your code will now work.

np.where will pick the 3333's from this array when it fails the logical or, as seen here in the documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html